# API Design for lost password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, passwords, actionmailer

What's the "best" way to implement lost password functionality in an API? I've split my app into two parts, one API and one client side (js MVC).

How do you do it? I'm also developing mobile apps for this app with the same API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby on Rails, you could use "devise" for authentication purpose. In case of mobile password recovery, you can create a custom action which returns the user's mail address from which the password info can be mailed...

Check [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for devise. Hope this helps...

Comment: The authentication part I've already built. This question was more about the design. So basically I shouldn't send the mail from the API?

Comment: actually you should send either the username or password... a factor which identifies the account uniquely...the user enters his new password or do u mail the password to the mail address?

Comment: I send an URL with a unique token the user use to access a form where a new password can be created. Perhaps I should do this in my client app.

Comment: sorry man.this is a bit new to me...i don wanna misguide you :)